# Excel how to apply a filter to a column with one value in it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

tl;dr How can we force Excel to lock-in a filter for a Column which only has 1 unique value within it?

I am having a very hard time coming up with a nice "label" for this problem, so I believe it is best if I do it with an example.  In these examples, I am using an excel sheet where Column 1 represents a list name and Column 2 represents values within each list.

## Example that works

I first filter on column 2, searching for "Royalties".

[image: Image showing only Royalties filter applied to column 2]

Now, I see that multiple lists from Column 1 match.  I am only interested in one of them, so I apply a filter to column 1.

[image: Image showing filters applied on both columns]

Finally, I want to see all values that are within that list, so I remove the filter from Column 2.

[image: Image showing filter from Column 2 removed]

## Example that is frustrating

So, I want to do the same thing except when the filter on Column 2 only results in a single list name in Column 1.

Let's repeat Step 1 from above, but by filtering Column 2 on "Rent or Royalties"

[image: Image showing filter on Column 2 that results in 1 result in Column 1]

Now, Column 1 only has 1 result.  What I would like to do is "lock in" a filter on Column 1 even though it is not necessary.  The reason is that, then, I want to remove the filter from Column 2 and see all values that fall within that list.

However, I can find no way to do that.  Instead of locking in the filter, Excel won't apply a filter to Column 1.  Then, when the filter is removed from Column 2, it shows all values in both columns.

## Question

The current workaround is to copy the value from Column 1 and paste it into Notepad (you can't keep it in memory because the filter action wipes the copied value).  Then, remove the Column 2 filter and then apply an "equal to" filter to Column 1.  However, I am wondering whether there is a better way to do this.

Please note that I would prefer a general solution.  The spreadsheets change and I would rather not use a macro / VBScript unless it is generic.

Thank you for taking the time to read this long post.

Regards,
Sachin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the copy to Notepad step if you reverse the order. First copy the value in Column 1 then apply a "Text Filters > Equals..." filter to Column 1 and paste the copied value. Now you can clear the filter from Column 2.

Comment: Excellent point.  And that actually does end up forcing a filter on Column 1 (since it must now do an explicit 'Equals' match).